# Backpropagation algorithm is stuck in MultiLayer Perceptron

Tags: python, algorithm, machine-learning, neural-network

I want to implement a MLP (MultiLayer Perceptron) to solve the XOR problem. I am crushing my head on it since a long time because I am not a great scientist, and I want to be sure to understand every line of this program.

I will begin by the questions:

1. Is there a **specific method for debugging a neural network** ? (such as predefined known weights that lead to an expected solution)
2. Is the following **backpropagation algorithm** (in pseudocode) **correct** ?
3. Should **the bias** be in this algorithm ? If not, is the bias necessary to solve the XOR problem ? And if yes, should the bias be 1 per neuron, 1 per layer or 1 per network ?
4. Is my python implementation correct ? If not, is it about the backpropagation, the forward propagation, the bias absence or otherthing ?

Every response is very welcome. It is not "homework", but if you are very afraid about it, I'll be very happy with only good tips. I still don't use properly numpy, because I'm more a dev than a scientist and have sometimes trouble with matrix equations (I'm currently working on it). Thus, it's very hard for me to well understand the different implementations I found.

---

**EDIT :** The algorithm works fine now, and I will highlight the different problems there was in the pseudocode / python implementation:

**The theory**:

- The **pseudocode was wrong** at the weights adjustement (I edited the code to mark the line WRONG with fix). I used the output layer outputs where I should use the inputs value
- It is effectively **possible to solve the XOR problem without bias** and only 1 hidden layer. What is interesting here is that it only works with 4 neurons in hidden layer or more, but not with 3. However, after benchmarks, adding the bias can considerably accelerate the time to optimum convergence (5x speeder or more)

**The python implementation**:

- The weights were initialized randomly between 0 and 1 and not between -1 and 1, it couldn't work like this.

Finally, [this resource](http://neuralnetworksanddeeplearning.com/chap1.html) was a big help to understand well the "neurons magic". It didn't help me to debug backpropagation, but it's now evidence that I could never make it work without more theorical knowledges. If, as me, you're more a dev than a scientist, I highly encourage you to check it out.

---

Based on the book "*Artifical intelligence for developers*" by Virginie MATHIVET, here is the **pseudocode for Backpropagation algorithm** (it's a french book, sorry for bad traductions):

```
While stop criteria is not achieved:
    Initialize d(i)

    For each example:
        Compute output value s(i)                          #1

        For each output neuron weight:                     #2
            d(i) = s(i) * (1 - s(i)) * (y(i) - s(i))
        EndFor

        For each hidden neuron weight:
            sum = 0
            For each link towards output neuron k:
                sum += d(k) * w(i->k)
            EndFor
            d(i) = o(i) * (1 - o(i)) * sum
        EndFor

        For each weight of the network:
            If link towards output neuron:
                w(i) += rate * d(i) * o(i)
            Else
                w(i) += rate * d(i) * s(i) # WRONG: s(i) should be input(i)
            EndIf
        EndFor
    EndFor
EndWhile
```

In the above, `d(x)` are the deltas, `o(x)` are the hidden layer outputs, `s(x)` are the output layer outputs, `y(x)` are the expected outputs and `w(x)` are the network weights.

I understand that line **#1** is the **forward propagation**, and the lines after **#2** (included) are about **backpropagation**. Thus, the proper algorithm can be written as:

```
While stop criteria is not achieved:
    Initialize d(i)

    For each example:
        output = Forward propagation with example inputs                  #1
        Backpropagation of the error between output and expected output   #2
    EndFor
EndWhile
```

My problem is that **the algorithm seems to go in circles** with the backpropagation algorithm and the weights changes, for example here are the outputs for the hidden layer:

```
[Epoch 0, inputs (1.0, 1.0)]: hidden outputs: None
[Epoch 0, inputs (0.0, 0.0)]: hidden outputs: [ 0.7755638   0.64556638  0.68163599]
[Epoch 0, inputs (1.0, 0.0)]: hidden outputs: [ 0.5  0.5  0.5]
[Epoch 0, inputs (0.0, 1.0)]: hidden outputs: [ 0.60747218  0.58975313  0.55246625]
[Epoch 1, inputs (1.0, 1.0)]: hidden outputs: [ 0.68911554  0.55079694  0.62718831]
[Epoch 1, inputs (1.0, 0.0)]: hidden outputs: [ 0.77449528  0.64107552  0.67770194]
[Epoch 1, inputs (0.0, 0.0)]: hidden outputs: [ 0.60728756  0.58957687  0.55230354]
[Epoch 1, inputs (0.0, 1.0)]: hidden outputs: [ 0.5  0.5  0.5]
[Epoch 2, inputs (0.0, 0.0)]: hidden outputs: [ 0.68877278  0.54872848  0.6254074 ]
[Epoch 2, inputs (1.0, 0.0)]: hidden outputs: [ 0.5  0.5  0.5]
[Epoch 2, inputs (1.0, 1.0)]: hidden outputs: [ 0.60700878  0.58812487  0.5509695 ]
[Epoch 2, inputs (0.0, 1.0)]: hidden outputs: [ 0.77344667  0.63591436  0.67311723]
[Epoch 3, inputs (0.0, 0.0)]: hidden outputs: [ 0.68856723  0.54708942  0.62400827]
[Epoch 3, inputs (1.0, 0.0)]: hidden outputs: [ 0.5  0.5  0.5]
```

Putting the examples in random order do not change anything. Moreover, I tried every learning rates (0.05 to 0.95) with the same result, so I think it's not about bad convergence. Here is my Python implementation:

```
def sigmoid(x):
    return 1 / (1 + np.exp(-x))

def dsigmoid(y):
    return y * (1.0 - y)

class NeuralNetwork:

    def __init__(self, nb_inputs, nb_hidden, nb_outputs, learning_rate):
        self.nb_inputs = nb_inputs
        self.nb_hidden = nb_hidden
        self.nb_outputs = nb_outputs
        self.learning_rate = learning_rate

        self.output_deltas = None
        self.output_weights = np.random.random((nb_outputs, nb_hidden)) # WRONG: should be between -1 and 1, not 0 and 1
        self.outputs = None
        self.hidden_deltas = None
        self.hidden_weights = np.random.random((nb_hidden, nb_inputs)) # WRONG: should be between -1 and 1, not 0 and 1
        self.hidden_outputs = None

    def forward_propagation(self, inputs):
        self.hidden_outputs = np.zeros((self.nb_hidden,))
        self.outputs = np.zeros((self.nb_outputs,))

        # get outputs for hidden layer
        for i in range(self.nb_hidden):
            aggregated = sum([inputs[j] * self.hidden_weights[i][j] for j in range(self.nb_inputs)])
            self.hidden_outputs[i] = sigmoid(aggregated)

        # get inputs for output layer
        for i in range(self.nb_outputs):
            aggregated = sum([self.hidden_outputs[j] * self.output_weights[i][j] for j in range(self.nb_hidden)])
            self.outputs[i] = sigmoid(aggregated)

    def backpropagation(self, expected_outputs):

        # find deltas for output layer 
        for i in range(self.nb_outputs):
            for j in range(self.nb_hidden):
                self.output_deltas[i][j] = dsigmoid(self.outputs[i]) * (expected_outputs[i] - self.outputs[i])

        # find deltas for hidden layer
        for i in range(self.nb_hidden):
            for j in range(self.nb_inputs):
                total = 0.0
                for k in range(self.nb_outputs):
                    total += self.output_deltas[k][i] * self.output_weights[k][i]
                self.hidden_deltas[i][j] = dsigmoid(self.hidden_outputs[i]) * total

        # change weights for output layer
        for i in range(self.nb_outputs):
            for j in range(self.nb_hidden):
                self.output_weights[i][j] += self.learning_rate * self.output_deltas[i][j] * self.outputs[i] # WRONG: should be self.hidden_outputs[j]

        # change weights for inputs layer
        for i in range(self.nb_hidden):
            for j in range(self.nb_inputs):
                self.hidden_weights[i][j] += self.learning_rate * self.hidden_deltas[i][j] * self.hidden_outputs[i] # WRONG: should be inputs[j]

    def train(self, data, nb_iterations):
        for i in range(nb_iterations):
            # Init deltas
            self.output_deltas = np.zeros((self.nb_outputs, self.nb_hidden), dtype=np.float64)
            self.hidden_deltas = np.zeros((self.nb_hidden, self.nb_inputs), dtype=np.float64)

            # Train on examples with different orders
            for inputs, expected_output in sorted(data.items(), key=lambda x: random.random()):
                expected_outputs = np.array([expected_output])

                self.forward_propagation(inputs)
                self.backpropagation(expected_outputs) # WRONG: need inputs: backpropagation(inputs, expected_outputs)

    def predict(self, inputs):
        self.forward_propagation(inputs)
        return self.outputs
```

Comment: `the algorithm seems to go in circles` <- typically an indicator of a learning rate that's too high

Comment: Thank you for your response. Unfortunately I tried a lot of learning rates (0.05 to 0.95) with exactly the same results. I edited my post with this precision

Comment: You can have a bias for each node and for each layer and it is also common to add these biases. An XOR problem can not be solved without a bias, apart from using 3 hidden neurons where one of them actually acts as a bias.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I am crushing my head on it since a long time because I am not a great
>   scientist, and I want to be sure to understand every line of this
>   program.

You got my answer on it. Continue like this, you'll rock!

**Disclaimer**: partial answer. I may improve it with the time.

> Is there a specific method for debugging a neural network ? (such as
>   predefined known weights that lead to an expected solution)

In general no. It is close to impossible on most real case due to the number of weights. You could still try to monitor neuron activity (the `aggregated` variable in your code) e.g. send the network similar inputs two times in a row and see if it *learns* i.e. it goes closer and closer to the right value.

> Is the following backpropagation algorithm (in pseudocode) correct ?

Will try to check.Is it from you?

> Should the bias be in this algorithm ? If not, is the bias necessary
>   to solve the XOR problem ? And if yes, should the bias be 1 per
>   neuron, 1 per layer or 1 per network ?

Usually there's 1 biais per neuron. No problem if you just ignore it.

> Is my python implementation correct ? If not, is it about the
>   backpropagation, the forward propagation, the bias absence or
>   otherthing ?

Will check. The bias absence is ok.

As a footnote, I would recommend this online "book": http://neuralnetworksanddeeplearning.com/chap1.html there's quite a lot of math, do not spend your time on math, try to get the concept. I find it super didactic.

Hope it help (a bit)
`pltrdy`

Comment: Thank you, it's very motivating ! I'm reassured to know that I don't miss any debugging method. I will try to monitor aggregated values. Concerning the bias, the answer of Jodo above say that one bias is necessary for resolving the XOR problem, are you sure that I can make a working program without it ? In other SO related questions, I didn't find a clear answer.

The pseudocode is from the french book "Intelligence artificielle pour les développeurs" by Virginie MATHIVET,

Thank you a lot for the resource, I will check it as soon as possible ! You are a great help !

Comment: I'm aware that the bias is only used to shift the activation function (sigmoid here), but I thought in XOR problem there is no need for it because we need range output between 0 and 1, but I'm probably wrong ?

Comment: My intuition is that it is not impossible without bias. I don't see how it could. Theorectically, more layers/neurons could solve the problem anyway. Still, it is obviously useful. It can be that your setup (nlayers x hidden_neurons) can't learn without bias.

Comment: Considering your second point, the sigmoid is 0 centered, so would indeed require shift for 0/1 value anyway

Comment: I guess I'll run your code tonight. I now want the answer as much as you i guess haha

Comment: Oh yes you're right ! Tomorrow I will reconsider my code and try with more hidden neurons / layers, and with a bias, and if it still does not work it probably means that my implementation is wrong somewhere.
You saved me a lot of time !

Comment: I tried more layers and more neurons with no results. I think there is a big problem in my backpropagation algorithm. Should the output layer deltas be the same for each weight ? Considering the algorithm at line: "d(i) = s(i) * (1 - s(i)) * (y(i) - s(i))", the first deltas calculation cannot be different each other, does it matter ?

Comment: Thank you a lot for your informations, all is now working fine ! Thanks to you, I can now make my firsts steps in the world of ANNs :) I'm working on it since 6 months, and I was sure that all I did was wrong. You've taken off my doubts concerning bias, number of layers, you gave me a great resource and I finally had motivation to debug it. Tonight I'll drink a shot to your honor !

Comment: Consider posting here as well, or edit my answer to put your solution on (as you validated my answer it would make sense). I havent done too much tho, happy it still helped ;)

Comment: or (best solution) put it all on github and link it :)